# alphalabel in multilanguage bibliography in biblatex with biber and babel

Tags: biblatex, babel, biber

I search and found no similar question.
I know **XeLatex** is a one of the solution, but it seems is doable in `Babel` also

My setup: **Miktex 2.9** with **Babel 2015/08/03 3.9m** and  **Biber 2.1**
This is MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,
style=alphabetic,
isbn=true,
url=true,
citestyle=alphabetic,
defernumbers=false,
sorting=nyt, 
bibencoding=utf8,
backend=biber,
language=auto,  
autolang=other,]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
Example one in Greek \textgreek{\cite{AlKarapan}},
 example two in Russian
  { \otherlanguage{russian}текст на русском \cite{CypinIstorijaRPC}     текст     на русском}   and example  in English again.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and **test.bib** is following:

```
@Book{AlKarapan,
author = {Καραπαναγοπούλου, Αλέξανδρος Κ.},
title = {Η Μεγάλη Σύνοδος της Ορθοδόξου Ανατολικής Εκκλησίας},
publisher = {auto-édition},
year = {\hbox{1990--1998}},
volumes = {6},
address = {Αθήνα},
hyphenation={greek},
langid={greek},
}
@Inbook{CypinIstorijaRPC,
author = {Владислав Цыпин},
title = {История Русской Церкви 1917--1997},
chapter = {VIII},
publisher = {Издательство Спасо-Преображенского Валаамского монастыря},
address = {Москва},
date = {1997},
urldate = {2010-10-25},
url = {http://old.pravoslavie.by/podpod.asp?id=135&Session=10},
langid={russian},
hyphenation={russian},
}
```

Now if you run pdflatex--biber-pdflatex you see
[image: no letters in bibliography]

error is:

```
Command \textKappa unavailable in encoding OT1. \endentry
```

and so on...

If you make main language Russian, you will see letters in key for Russian bibentry but not in Greek bibentry.

Solution is following:
Open generated bbl file and find  `labelalpha` field entry

```
  \field{labelalpha}{Καρ98}
```

and

```
  \field{labelalpha}{Цып97}
```

and add there appropriate `\otherlanguage` command entries as

```
  \field{labelalpha}{\otherlanguage{greek}Καρ98}
```

and

```
  \field{labelalpha}{\otherlanguage{russian}Цып97}
```

save it and just run pdflatex..Errors are gone and everything is OK..

So question is How can i addd otherlanguage call to labelalpha entries without
editing bbl file? can biblatex do this? I thin it is natural since keys are generated by langid so `\otherlanguage` or in general `labelalpha`'s language
needs to be same as `langid`

p.s.
I encountered this problem with, English, Russian,Greek,Georgian setup. No matter which language is set as main language for document...adding 'otherlanguage' call solves the problem..Example was shortened for demo.

edited: just added image how bibliography looks after editing `.bbl` file adding 'otherlanguage' calls[image]

I think `language=auto` or similar option needs to applied for keys in bibliography list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing we are missing from `language=auto` and `autolang=other` is that they neglect to wrap the `label` in the bibliography into `foreignlanguage` or `otherlanguage`. That is easily fixed with the following definition

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{%
  \iffieldundef{langid}
    {#1}
    {\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{#1}}%
}
```

This does exactly what you did with your `.bbl` file, but automatically.
Of course, we can only really do that if the `langid` field is present, so we check that first.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{AlKarapan,
author = {Καραπαναγοπούλου, Αλέξανδρος Κ.},
title = {Η Μεγάλη Σύνοδος της Ορθοδόξου Ανατολικής Εκκλησίας},
publisher = {auto-édition},
date = {1990/1998},
volumes = {6},
address = {Αθήνα},
langid={greek},
}
@Inbook{CypinIstorijaRPC,
author = {Владислав Цыпин},
title = {История Русской Церкви 1917--1997},
chapter = {VIII},
publisher = {Издательство Спасо-Преображенского Валаамского монастыря},
address = {Москва},
date = {1997},
urldate = {2010-10-25},
url = {http://old.pravoslavie.by/podpod.asp?id=135&Session=10},
langid={russian},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[russian,greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,
style=alphabetic,
isbn=true,
url=true,
defernumbers=false,
sorting=nyt, 
backend=biber,
language=auto,  
autolang=other]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{%
  \iffieldundef{langid}
    {#1}
    {\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{#1}}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{AlKarapan,CypinIstorijaRPC,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: You mentioned it in your question, but I would still like to repeat that for documents such as this XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are the real solutions. The document (minus `fontenc` and `inputenc`, plus `fontspec` using Linux Libertine) compiled fine and showed the labels as expected out of the box without resorting to any hackery.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And this is becouse langid sets, beside language , fontenc, when seelcting language and in 8bit TeX  language=hyphen does not make too much sense, becouse if it switches fontenc, then bibentry is not readable. Let imagine  case: User needs to diplay bibentry information in language it is present(so he sets langid), he also adds hypenation language entry different than langid(as long as hyphenation language „stays“ in same encoding as langid language), but he wants lbx translations in main document language, which can be different from langid.

Comment: He will get errors with 8bit TeX. To solve this this biblatex needs one more lang key to work with 8bit TeX and coding changies..IF aothor of biblatex will implement it this will be great..I think classic TeX will live :)

Comment: I guess I can wrap other fields as well? i mean fields mentioned in lbx files. To have result i have mentioned in comment: biblentry in langid and tranlateble things from lbx file in main language>. i know this is different question but can you give example for that? :)

Comment: and why indents in bibliography are different in your answer result, than in images i have posted?

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Indeed with `autolang=other`, we switch not only hyphenation, but also lots of other language-related components. You might want to ask another new question about whether it is possible to make sure the contents of all fields are displayed correctly without switching the localisation. I'm not sure if I got everything you wanted to bring across and was slightly confused about your point  on `langid` and `hyphenation`: the latter is the legacy version of the former. In older versions of `biblatex`, the field determining the entry language was called `hyphenation` ...

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili .... but now it is called `langid` to reflect a slight extension of its original concept. Again, for that I would urge you to ask a new question. (I'm not really sure whether and how these things are supposed to work with BIbTeX8, with Biber they work fine.)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili The indentation in the image is off because I used a slightly different way to achieve what you wanted before that (amongst other issues) caused this trouble and I neglected to update the previed image, I will do so shortly.

Comment: ok, thanks...i didnot know that hyphenation field is oblotete..