# Switching to multi language in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, xetex

I have a xelatex file. I write article. The article is in Persian language. In the article I use Persian references and English references. I want Persian reference alignment rtl and English reference ltr. But my references only right or only left. I uses in imporet reference with jebref application.

For example: [image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you please post a compilable minimal document that shows what you are doing. It should contain only code to show the problem, but needs to include the bibliography package you are using (I assume `biblatex`?) and two bib items, one in Persian and the other in English. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for some more details on how to do this.

Comment: use biblatex with langid see for example this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260583/alphalabel-in-multilanguage-bibliography-in-biblatex-with-biber-and-babel this is with pdflatex but with xelatex will be same..ypu maybe will need to change 'language=auto,  
autolang=other' options see biblatex documentation

Comment: Given the amount of informationi in the question there is no real answer to give. The proposed solution by the OP isn't helpful for other users, as it stands. I vote to close as unclear.